# Valid values for ID attribute while using JQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html4

What are all the valid values for ID attribute for html element while using JQuery selectors? JQuery following HTML4 rules or HTML5 rules for ID attribute?

Comment: The same rules for HTML5 apply to jQuery. Just be aware you need to escape some characters which have special meanings in selectors, such as `[`, `]`, and `.`

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Goto link ,i think it will help you

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201011/html5_allows_almost_any_value_for_the_id_attribute_use_wisely/

Comment: This is cannot be considered as an answer. This can be posted as a comment.